# RoR random four users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know how I could display a list of 4 random users in RoR.

I know there is the rand() method, but I would have to apply this to an array somehow.

Answer (score 2):

If the table does not contain too many entries the following will return four randomly chosen users:

```
User.find(:all, :order => 'RANDOM()', :limit => 4)
```

However, this doesn't scale since it randomizes the *entire* table.  For tables with lots of columns this can be very IO intensive.

Another method is to only randomize the `id` and then select only those rows.  Something along the lines of:

```
# Return an array of ids randomly drawn from User
ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values(
        User.send(:construct_finder_sql, { :select => 'id', 
                                           :order => 'RANDOM()',
                                           :limit => 4
                                         }))

# Return the users drawn from above
users = User.find(:all, :conditions => "id IN (#{ids.join(',')})")
```

If you go with this, I would encapsulate it as a class method of `User`.

Comment: this is what I get: SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: rand:

Comment: For SQLite, the function is `RANDOM()`.